# Finding rotation axis and angle in matrx

Tags: c#, algorithm, 3d, xna-4.0

I am trying to extract the axis of rotation and the angle of rotation from a 3x3 rotation 
matrix. I am currently using this method but am unsure if I am on track. I am running into issues elsewhere in my program and am thinking this may be a cause but have been unable to verify this myself.

I am working with the XNA framework, if that helps. I looked into using Matrix.Decompose() which returns the scale (vec3) translation(vec3) and rotation(quaternion) but I am not sure that I can extract the data data I need from these values.

```
public static void MatrixRotationAxisAngle(Matrix m, ref float theta, ref Vector3 rot_axis) {
        float trace = m.M11 + m.M22 + m.M33;
        float cos_theta = 0.5f * (trace - 1.0f);
        if (cos_theta > 0.999999875f) {
            //allow some epsilon value
            theta = 0.0f;
            rot_axis = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        } else if (cos_theta > -0.999999875f) {

            theta = (float)Math.Acos(cos_theta);
            rot_axis.X = (m.Up.Z - m.Forward.Y);
            rot_axis.Y = (m.Forward.X - m.Right.Z);
            rot_axis.Z = (m.Right.Y - m.Up.X);
            rot_axis.Normalize();

        } else { //angle within PI limits
            theta = (float)Math.PI;
            //find index of largest diag term in matrix
            int index = 0;

            if (m.M11 > m.M22 && m.M11 > m.M33) {
                index = 0;
            }
            if (m.M22 > m.M11 && m.M22 > m.M33) {
                index = 1;
            }
            if (m.M33 > m.M11 && m.M33 > m.M22) {
                index = 2;
            }

            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    float ix = 1.0f / rot_axis.X;
                    rot_axis.X = (float)Math.Sqrt(m.M11 + 1.0f);
                    rot_axis.Y = m.M12 * ix;
                    rot_axis.X = m.M13 * ix;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    float iy = 1.0f / rot_axis.Y;
                    rot_axis.Y = (float)Math.Sqrt(m.M22 + 1.0f);
                    rot_axis.X = m.M21 * iy;
                    rot_axis.Z = m.M23 * iy;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    float iz = 1.0f / rot_axis.Y;
                    rot_axis.Z = (float)Math.Sqrt(m.M33 + 1.0f);
                    rot_axis.X = m.M31 * iz;
                    rot_axis.Y = m.M32 * iz;
                    break;
            }
            rot_axis.Normalize();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to take a look into the pseudocode from [this mathematical explanation (pdf)](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/EulerAngles.pdf), Chapter 2.1 (depending on your matrix). I have successfully used the code in one of my projects, and it returned valid results in my case.

Answer (score 0):

See the matrix in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations .

As you can see finding theta is pretty easy. Use that in other equations to find the other angles.